# chrome extension getting session data from website

Tags: django, api, google-chrome, session, google-chrome-extension

in my django project, i have a url that has `login_required` set, because i need the `request.user` variable in it to process some data,

i also created a simple chrome extension where i'm going to have to send requests to that django project url.

i do not want to use the username and password in the extension to login and send the request

i want to:

- redirect the user when the extension is installed to the my website
- they will login,
- the extension will know that the user has logged in and it will get (and save) a key that i could maybe inject in the page after login is successful
- the key can be used as a query parameter in the request in order to identify the user without any username and password

i'm sorry if this seems as a stupid question, but i'm very confused on how to do this

PS: i have already a system in place where the user can use a key in order to make requests without logging in,
i just need a way to open a tab when the extension is installed, and login then get the key (which is injected in the page after login), and save it to use it in the extension later.

Comment: It doesn't seem a stupid question, but it's too broad and vague. Depending on how the site processes sign-in you can either use something trivial like XMLHttpRequest or a dedicated chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow.

Comment: @wOxxOm the sign-in in the website is simple, i'm sending a post request with username and password, and returning json that contains login_success property (true or false), what i'm trying to do, is be able to do requests inside the extension after doing an authentication (only once) in the website (the first time the extension is installed)

Comment: It could be indeed very simple, in which case this is something you would immediately see yourself after reading the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) in the extension documentation, but I still don't know what exactly you're doing there and what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the extension is opened for the first time, I'm showing the user a login page. The login page sends the username & password to an API where they are authenticated. If the information is correct, the required user info is returned (mainly the API key). The information is then saved to local storage.

```js
var username = document.querySelector('[name="username"]');
var password = document.querySelector('[name="password"]');

$.ajax({
    URL : 'https://example.com/api/extension-auth/',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'username': username.value.trim(),
        'password': password.value.trim(),
    }),
    success: res => {
        if (res.api_key) {
            browser.storage.sync.set({ 'user_data': {'api_key': api_key} }, () => {
                // show extension main logged in page
            });
        }
        else {
            // show invalid login information alert
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        // show server error aler 
    },
});
```

Everytime the extension is opened the local storage is checked

```js
browser.storage.sync.get('user_data', data => {
    if (data.user_data) {
        if (valid_api_key(data.user_data.api_key)) {
            // show extension main logged in page
        }
        else {
            // show login page
        }
    }
    else {
        // show login page
    }
});
```

the `valid_api_key` function makes a random call to the API to check if there is not an authentication error.

Then, I use the saved API key from local storage to do API requests.